# How can I retain the state of a checkbox in MVC/razor?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have this checkbox and it works... but each time the form submits the checkbox gets unchecked. You wouldn't **believe** the time and frustration I've spent on forums and Google looking at all but the answer I need to this seemingly simple problem. Wasted morning.

Here's where the checkbox shows up in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p> Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("searchString") <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
    <p>Show only my posts: <input type="checkbox" name="authorFilter" onchange="this.form.submit();"/></p>

}
```

And here's where the controller handles this stuff:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    var posts = from p in db.BlogPosts
                select p;

    var authorFilterCheck = Request.Form["authorFilter"];

    if (authorFilterCheck == "on")
    {
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        posts = posts.Where(i => i.AuthorID.Equals(userID));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        posts = posts.Where(
            x =>
                x.Body.Contains(searchString) ||
                x.Title.Contains(searchString));

    return View(posts);
}
```

So when it's checked, it adds a filter and the page refreshes. But when it refreshes the checkbox is unchecked (but the filter is still applied) so that you can never remove the filter (plus the empty checkbox missleads the user into thinking there's no filter)...

Here's the model in case it's needed:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Authored")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

}
```

There's nothing about the checkbox in my model because presumably that would add its bool to all the entries in the table. Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: Rather use a Viewbag to hold the checked data, that way you dont have to include it in the model, if you are using `IEnumreable<model>` for your model, if the bool is inside an instance of model, use `Model[index of specific model class].IsChecked.`

Comment: In the mean time I managed to finagle some functionality by stumbling through the ViewBag approach (which isn't something I leaned in my tutorials) but I still wish I could understand how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model representing what you want to display/edit

```
public class BlogPostsVM
{
  [Display(Name = "Search Criteria")]
  public string SearchText { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Include my posts only")]
  public bool IncludeUserPostsOnly { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<BlogPost> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view, change the form method to a GET and strongly bind to your model

```
@model BlogPostsVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchText)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IncludeUserPostsOnly)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IncludeUserPostsOnly)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

@foreach(var post in Model.Posts)
{
    // Display the blog posts
}
```

Note: Do not handle the checkbox click event!

and modify the Index method to

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchText, bool includeUserPostsOnly)
{

    var posts = from p in db.BlogPosts select p;
    if (includeUserPostsOnly)
    {
        string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        posts = posts.Where(i => i.AuthorID.Equals(userID));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        posts = posts.Where(x => x.Body.Contains(searchText) || x.Title.Contains(searchText));
    }
    BlogPostsVM model = new BlogPostsVM
    {
        SearchText = searchText,
        IncludeUserPostsOnly = includeUserPostsOnly,
        Posts = posts
    };
    return View(model );
}
```

Side note: you will get better performance by posting the values using ajax and returning a partial view of the filtered results and then updating the current page rather that generating a new page each time.

Comment: Nice! I think that will actually work. Plus, novice as I am it's an opportunity to learn to build a view model! Very well explained by the way. I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: Awesome TY @Stephan Muecke! This is what I was looking for. Question and Comment... **Question:** Would you say this is using "strongly typed model" as the others have suggested? **Comment:** I had to take some extra steps so I'll edit your answer and if it could have been done better/differently, feel free to re-edit.

Comment: I have rejected your edit. The code you were proposing is not necessary at all. You just need `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Posts [0].AuthorName)` - it will work even if there are no elements in the collection

Comment: Also if you want the `bool` to be optional, the correct approach is to use `bool? includeUserPostsOnly` (i.e. nullable) and then you can check using `if (includeUserPostsOnly.HasValue && includeUserPostsOnly.Value)`

Comment: I figured there was a better way - just had to get it working. Thanks for the updates. I'll go simplify my code with it!

Comment: Actually I'm getting an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<Posts>'" - the approach makes sense though. What else is needed?

Comment: Oops. Its `IEnumerable<T>` not `List<T>` so you can use `m => m.Posts.FirstOrDefault().AuthorName` (or make the property `List<Posts>`

Comment: Got it. Another that worked was m.Posts.Elementat(0)... I like yours better though. Still not quite sold on all the extra stuff for the optional/nullable bool but if it will come back to bite me, I'll add the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Approach you are using is not good. **Strongly type model** is preferable in MVC pattern as @PaRiMal Raj said. As you are new I am just making the answer more organized. First **create a model** like this to send data from form to controller:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    public string searchString {get ; set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get ; set;}
}
```

Now change the **View code** like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.searchString)                    
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchString)       
   <p>Show only my posts: </p>
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
   <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
```

**In Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid){
       return View(model);
     }
    var posts = from p in db.BlogPosts
            select p;   
    if (model.Ischecked)
    {
       string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
       posts = posts.Where(i => i.AuthorID.Equals(userID));
    }
  string searchString=model.searchString;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    posts = posts.Where(
        x =>
            x.Body.Contains(searchString) ||
            x.Title.Contains(searchString));

 return View(posts);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: _It makes me feel a little closer but I'm having a couple problems:_ **1)** CheckBoxFor still doesn't want to take any model properties (though DisplayNameFor readily recognizes them) _AND_ **2)** views can only accept one at-model statement so I'm not clear on whether I'm supposed to have a new model (which I'm calling "BlogFilter") that contains a searchString and IsChecked property and add it to my BlogPost model as a property itself, or just directly add those two to the BlogPost model... since adding a second BlogFilter at-model statement to the view returns an error.

Comment: I guess I'm also not entirely clear on how my model isn't "strongly typed" - perhaps you could point me to a resource from which I can get a better grasp on what that means?

Comment: If you already have a model then create a viewmodel merging previous model and new model.I mean which will fulfill your requirement to communicate with controller. you can see the answer of @Stephen Muecke.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use strongly typed model, it would make things a lot easier

your model should be something like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public book IsChecked {get ; set;}
}
```

to use this

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // here you will get if its checked or not
        return View(model); // it will preserve the state
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new MyModel();
      model.IsChecked = false; // it is false by default anyways
      return View();
    }
}
```

render dropdown this way

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
```

Comment: I did attempt to implement this by adding a bool to my model but it behaves oddly, either because I'm not getting it, or because the view is using an IEnumerable<BlogPost> and doesn't know what to do with a whole table of entries with a bool that's only needed once.

Comment: I'm also finding that @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked) isn't acceptable. It works fine with @Html.DIsplayFor and other helpers, but CheckBoxFor doesn't want to take model properties... Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Lastly, I went ahead and added my model to the OP for clarity. Thanks for your help!